# PIL (Pillow) module install issue

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I have been attempting to install the Pillow (PIL) module into my python(3.8.2) using Windows 10 to no success.

I have tried executing `pip install Pillow` as mentioned by the website in my cmd but both `pip` and `python` are '*not recognised as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file*'

What I have tried:

Reinstalled both pip and python and tried again, with the same problem.

Using powershell instead of command prompt (not sure if that makes any difference).

Also I understand you can download the Pillow module package in .whl, but I couldn't work out how to install it that way.

I have also installed pygame using the cmd before which baffles me as to why this is happening.

Any and all help is appreciated, Thank you!

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: Windows 10, I will edit the question as I imagine that is important.

Comment: Try ```python -m pip install pillow```

Comment: If you mean in the cmd, it still returns  " 'python' is not a recognised internal or external command "

Comment: `python3 -m pip install --upgrade Pillow
` via  - https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation.html#windows-installation

Comment: you should use a virtual environment for python projects.

Answer (score 1):

If you're sure that you've successfully installed python, but it's not working on your commandline, it may not be in your PATH. Open the search in the windows start menu, and type "env" and click on "Edit Environmental Variables for your system (or choose account if you don't have admin on the system). If you chose system, click on the environmental variables button. You will then be greeted by one window split into two menus, User Variables and System Variables. Scroll down in the User variables and double click on Path.

Go find the location of your python install with the python.exe file in it (you could search for it in your C:\ if you're willing to wait). Add that path to the Path variable list.

If you can't find the python.exe or just don't want to wait, reinstall your python installation and look for a checkbox with "Add to Path" or something along those lines.

In addition to the python.exe being in your path, make sure to add the "Scripts" folder in your path. It should be a subfolder in the same folder as python.exe.

Comment: I refreshed my cmd after changing these things and it does register that python exists, except I now have a syntax error after using ```python -m pip install pillow``` (specifically the ```pip``` part) do I need to set the environment variables for pip too? Thank you!

Comment: In addition to the python folder being in your path, make sure that you also add the "Scripts" folder to the path as well. This folder contains the pip.exe.

Answer (score 0):

For windows 10 install `PIL` and `cImage`.

- Install Python 2.7.8 (64-bit — this is important)
  https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.8/python-2.7.8.amd64.msi
- Install Python 3.4.1 (64-bit — this is important)
  https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.4.1/python-3.4.1.amd64.msi
- Download and install Pillow for Python 2
  https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.7/P/Pillow/Pillow-2.5.3.win-amd64-py2.7.exe#md5=33c3a581ff1538b4f79b4651084090c8
- Download and install Pillow for Python 3
  https://pypi.python.org/packages/3.4/P/Pillow/Pillow-2.5.3.win-amd64-py3.4.exe#md5=6ee659d7b945e826a07c53c15578424f (direct link)
  https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow/ (all other versions)

Download and install cImage

- Navigate to https://github.com/bnmnetp/cImage
- Click cImage.py, and click the button labeled Raw to see the contents of the file.
- Click File > Save Page As (Chrome & Firefox) or File > Save As (Safari) to save the file on your computer.
- Copy “cImage.py” from where you saved it to C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages and C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\

Comment: Link only answers are not encouraged for SO. If the link goes down your answer means nothing.